# Implement ng.IFilterService in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angularjs-filter

I have the following in a .ts file

```
module App.Filters {
    export class SplitRangeFilter implements ng.IFilterService {
        static $inject = ['$filter'];

        public static factory(): Function {
            return (input: string, splitIndex: number) => {
                return input.split('-')[splitIndex];
            }
        }
    }

    angular.module("App.Filters", []).filter('SplitRange', () => SplitRangeFilter.factory);
}
```

and it is giving me a compiler error of:

`Class SplitRangeFilter declared interface IFilterService but does not implement it: Types 'SplitRangeFilter' and 'IFilterService' have incompatible signatures. No matching signature for '<T>(name: string) => T'`

I cannot find any such signature in angulars documentation. Any suggestions on how to get rid of this compiler error in VS2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want it to work and aren't concerned about implementing the "right" interface then remove the `implements ng.IFilterService` and then change your Angular registration statement to execute the factory (i.e. add `()`)

```
angular.module("App.Filters", []).filter('SplitRange', () => SplitRangeFilter.factory());
```

Answer (score 3):

The IFilterService is only used to add type safety via TypeScript compiler to programmatic filter invokes.

The correct implementation based on your code would be:

```
module App.Filters {
    // Add filter type to the filter service so that TypeScript can
    // perform type  checking on future programmatic invokes.
    // This app filter service
    export interface IAppFilterService extends angular.IFilterService {
        (name: 'SplitRange'): (input: string | splitIndex: number) => string | undefined;
    }
    export class SplitRangeFilter {
        constructor() {
            return (input: string, splitIndex: number): string | undefined => {
                return input.split('-')[splitIndex];
            }
        }
    }

    angular.module("App.Filters", []).filter('SplitRange', SplitRangeFilter);
}
```

This is how IAppFilterService will be used in your code:

```
// Usage for IAppFilterService
class AppController {
    constructor(private $filter: IAppFilterService) {}

    // This will pass without compile warnings
    public splitString(val: string, index: number): string | undefined {
        return this.$filter('SplitRange')(val, number);
    }

    // This will throw compile time TypeScript error
    public splitNumber(val: number, index: number): string | undefined {
        return this.$filter('SplitRange')(val, number);
    }
}
```